# MissingManifestResourceException error

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a resources file which is in the same level as my .cs file.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
ResourceManager res = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("Resource1", ".",      null);
string s = res.GetString("String1");
```

However, this gives the following exception:

> MissingManifestResourceException Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on
>   disk. baseName: Resource1  locationInfo:   fileName:
>   Resource1.resources

How could I resolve this?

Comment: What's the filename of the resource?

Comment: "At the same level as my .cs file" is unwise.  You don't normally ship your entire project along with the compiled program to your customer.  Using a relative path like "." is equally unwise, it critically depends on Environment.CurrentDirectory which is not predictable.  And just plain wrong when you debug your program since the file is located at `..\..`.  You must copy the file.  Do favor Project + Properties + Resources, it never gets this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`resourceDir` is name of the directory to search for the resources. resourceDir can be an absolute path or **a relative path from the application directory**.

so you can not make it relative to your `.cs` containing directory.

Comment: It's actually the same folder

Comment: Still no luck with that change.